# How to mock generics using Easymock only?

Tags: class, generics, easymock

I want to mock generic class which extends E interface using EasyMock framework. I am struggling with this since last week. **Any help would be appreciated.**

```
//X.class
Class<? extends E> type;  // I want to mock and write nicemock of this line using EasyMock only

public final Simple limit(){

if(A.class.isAssignableFrom(type)){   // I want to write expect statement using EasyMock
  //some statements
 }
```

Comment: I really don't know what you are trying to achieve. No mock is needed here. Can you provide a full test case?

Comment: I want to mock Class <? extends E> type; in my test class, also I want to write expect for if statement. I am writing test case for limit().

Comment: An instance of type or the type Class itself/